# Scheduled export from SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a need to export the data from the table into .csv file and do it schedulled. I've not work much on SQL developer before, mainly on SQL Server. So what options do i have to do this auto export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a Powershell fan, I'd point your attention to this [tutorial](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/04/use-oracle-odp-net-and-powershell-to-simplify-data-access.aspx).

Though SQL Developer not involved.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Developer has a command line interface, SDcli - you'll find it in your SQL Developer BIN directory.

You can build a 'cart' in the SQL Developer GUI, and save it to a file. This cart's contents are database objects, including tables.

[image]

You can ask to export the contents of your cart to various file formats, including CSVs for the data.

Here's what the CLI looks like

[image]

[Detailed example here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2016/06/shopping-for-csv-with-sql-developers-cart/).

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL developer does not have the feature to do schedule export of the dataset. You will need to write a PL/SQL code using UTL_FILE/ SPOOL and schedule it using either Oracle Scheduler or some other Scheduling tool.

Hope it helps

Vishad